# How can I get a Material UI React Textfield to not be overlayed by text, when it has position sticky and it has been scrolled up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**Context:**

I have a little chat app with the chat in the middle, and a sticky textfield on the bottom. I want to have it when I scroll up the chatlist, that the Textfield will always be on the bottom but over the chat messages (so it has zIndex presedence).

**The Problem:**

But when I scroll now, the `TextField` from react material ui, is behind the text, almost like it has a opacity or something.

**What have I tried:**

I have set a high zIndex on the `TextField` and also Elevation, but nothing changes the problem.

Code snippet of the TextField:

```
<div
      style={{
        position: "sticky",
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >

      <TextField
        placeholder="Your Message.."
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        label="message"
        color="primary"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => (e.keyCode === 13 ? submitMessage() : null)}
      />
    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot how it looks currently:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add background-color to the TextField...

```
  <TextField
    placeholder="Your Message.."
    variant="outlined"
    fullWidth
    label="message"
    color="primary"
    value={"aaaaaaaaaaa"}
    onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
    onKeyDown={(e) => (e.keyCode === 13 ? submitMessage() : null)}
    style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}
  />
```

Comment: Yes that works, but the label is still not looking very good: https://imgur.com/a/xPZy0Dr

But that solves it for me, guess just don't use a label in this use case. Thank you very much. So in conclusion, always set the background color same as the parent?

Comment: You can add backgroundColor to the label as well. And in this case yes, you want the color to be the same as you have in messages

Comment: By adding this prop: `InputLabelProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: "white" } }}` ?

Comment: yeah, that is one way

Comment: Is there a better way? :D You are a hero btw. I will acceppt your answer

Comment: I was rather thinking about something like: root: {
        '& label.MuiInputLabel-shrink': {
            backgroundColor: white
        }
}